# Alert with instructions before gameplay starts

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

How can I add an alert that displays instructions before game starts:

See code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (questions && configDictionary) {

        [questionLabel setText:[[questions objectAtIndex:currentQuestonIndex] objectForKey:@"question"]];
        NSArray *answers = [[questions objectAtIndex:currentQuestonIndex] objectForKey:@"answers"];
        [answerLabel0 setText:[answers objectAtIndex:0]];
        [answerLabel1 setText:[answers objectAtIndex:1]];
        [answerLabel2 setText:[answers objectAtIndex:2]];
        [answerLabel3 setText:[answers objectAtIndex:3]];
        [pointsPerAnswerLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%d points", [[configDictionary objectForKey:kPointsPerCorrectAnswer] intValue]]];
        [currentQuestionNumberLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"question %d", currentQuestonIndex+1]];
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to show an alertmessage before that piece of code happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UIAlertView`:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Instructions" 
    message:@"Your Instructions..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
    otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]; 

    [alert show];
```

If you want to alert the user every time the app launches place it in the

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    }
```

**Edit**

You said you wanted to start the game after the dismiss button is pressed. So take advantage of the `UIAlertView delegate`:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0){

        //Start your game!

    }

}
```

Comment: but my game starts before the cancel button is pressed

Comment: @user1585646 what do you mean with the game continues? are you using some framework for games?

Comment: Why don't you have a separate button to start the game. You can also implement the `UIAlertView Delegate` and have the game start as soon as the dismiss button is clicked.

Comment: @NSPunk the alert view comes up but i don't want the game to start until after the cancelButton is pressed

Comment: Use the `UIAlertView` delegate method!. Look at my revised answer.

Comment: @Imirak but where do i put it in my code? sorry i'm new to this...thanks for your help

Comment: @Imirak do i keep my viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes you can keep your `viewDidLoad`. Just place the game starting code in the `if (buttonIndex == 0)` conditional because that is fired once you click `dismiss` on the alert that opens every time the app opens.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"How to play"
                                                  message:@"Answer the questions correctly to get points blablabla..."
                                                 delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
[message show];
```

Comment: but my game still continues before the cancel button is pressed